# creating Linux app from existing wpf program using xamarin

Tags: c#, linux, wpf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having a program created in wpf (using MVVM pattern) and I want this to work in linux too. I read about xamarin but couldn't find any tutorial how to implement such thing. Can anyone explain if it is even possible to somehow use my existing program with xamarin (in visual studio) and run it on Linux? And if so, how should I do this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Xamarin to develop a Linux desktop application using C#. With [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/) (Xamarin Studio was originally forked from this project) you can develop GTK# applications that could be suited for your needs.

The problem with WPF is that Mono (the open source implementation of .NET) is only a subset of .NET and doesn't have any implementation for WPF, [nor does it have any plans to implement it](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/wpf/).

So the takeaway from this is that you can still reuse almost all of the core code from your existing application but to make it run on Linux you'll have to rework the UI layer.